# Image analysis function to calculate middle gray level (max(z)+min(z)/2 in Java

Tags: java, image-processing

How do I calculate the middle gray level `(max(z)+min(z)/2` over the points where the structuring element is 1 and sets the output pixel to that value?

I just know a little about how to get the RGB value each pixel by using `image.getRGB(x,y)`. I have no idea how to get gray level value each pixel of the image and what is `z` in the formula and all that?

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you actually tried? What type of input are you working with?

Comment: I am working with images of any format jpg pr png or others

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that `z` are the pixels within your structuring element.  I'm also going to assume that "structuring element" is in the case of morphology.  Here are a few pointers before we start:

1. You can convert a colour pixel to its graylevel intensity by using the Luminance formula.  By consulting the [SMPTE Rec. 709 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luma_%28video%29#Rec._601_luma_versus_Rec._709_luma_coefficients), the output graylevel intensity, given the RGB components is: `Y = 0.2126*R + 0.7152*G + 0.0722*B`.
2. We're going to assume that the structuring element is **odd**.  This will allow for the symmetric analysis of the structuring element for each pixel in your image where it is placed
3. I'm going to assume that your image is already loaded in as a [`BufferedImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html).
4. Your structuring element will be a 2D array of `int`.
5. I'm not going to process those pixels where the structuring element traverses out of bounds to make things easy.

---

As such, the basic algorithm is this:

1. For each pixel in our image, place the centre of the structuring element at this location
2. For each pixel location where the structuring element is 1 that coincides with this position, find the max and minimum graylevel intensity
3. Set the output image pixel at this location to be `(max(z) + min(z)) / 2)`.

---

Without further ado:

```
public BufferedImage calculateMiddleGray(BufferedImage img, int[][] mask)
{
    // Declare output image
    BufferedImage outImg = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(),
            img.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    // For each pixel in our image...
    for (int i = mask.length/2; i < img.getWidth() - mask.length/2; i++) {
        for (int j = mask[0].length/2; j < img.getHeight() - mask[0].length/2; j++) {
            int maxPix = -1;
            int minPix = 256;
            // For each pixel in the mask...
            for (int x = -mask.length/2; x <= mask.length/2; x++) {
                for (int y = -mask[0].length/2; y <= mask[0].length/2; y++) {

                   //Obtain structuring element pixel
                   int structPix = mask[y+mask.length/2][x+mask[0].length/2];

                   // If not 1, continue
                   if (structPix != 1)
                       continue;                      

                   // Get RGB pixel
                   int rgb = img.getRGB(i+x, j+y);
                   // Get red, green and blue channels individually
                   int redPixel = (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
                   int greenPixel = (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
                   int bluePixel = rgb & 0xFF;

                   // Convert to grayscale
                   // Performs SMPTE Rec. 709 lum. conversion using integer logic
                   int lum = (77*red + 150*green + 29*blue) >> 8;

                   // Find max and min appropriately
                   if (lum > maxPix)
                       maxPix = lum;
                   if (lum < minPix)
                       minPix = lum;
              }
           }
           // Set output pixel
           // Grayscale image has all of its RGB pixels equal
           int outPixel = (maxPix + minPix) / 2;
           // Cap output - Ensure we don't go out of bounds
           if (outPixel > 255)
               outPixel = 255;
           if (outPixel < 0)
               outPixel = 0;
           int finalOut = (outPixel << 16) | (outPixel << 8) | outPixel;
           outImg.setRGB(i, j, finalOut);
       }
   }
}
```

To call this method, create an image `img` using [any standard method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html), then create a structuring element `mask` that is a 2D integer array.  After, place this method in your class, then invoke the method by:

```
BufferedImage outImg = calculateMiddleGray(img, mask);
```

Also (and of course), make sure you import the necessary package for the `BufferedImage` class, or:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
```

---

**Note**: This is **untested** code.  Hope it works!